# How can I fix "ObjectContext instance has been disposed error"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, singleton, repository

I developed an application with entity framework. I get the "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."error from sometimes.

I did some research on the internet but I couldn't figure it out. I would be very grateful if you could help

My DatabaseContext :

```
   public class DatabaseContext :DbContext 
    {
       public DbSet<EvernoteUser> EvernoteUsers { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Liked> Likes { get; set; }

       public DatabaseContext()
       {           
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DatabaseContext,Configuration>()); 

        }

    }
```

My Repository:

```
public class Repository<T> :IRepository<T> where T : class   
    {        
        private DatabaseContext db;       
            public Repository()
        {
            db = RepositoryBase.CreateContext();

        }

        public List<T> List() 
        {
            return db.Set<T>().ToList(); 
        }

        public List<T> List(Expression<Func<T,bool>> where)
        {
            return db.Set<T>().Where(where).ToList();
        }

        public T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            return db.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(where);
        }

        public IQueryable<T> ListQueryable() 
        {
            return db.Set<T>().AsQueryable<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

My RepositoryBase class:

```
 class RepositoryBase
    {

        protected RepositoryBase()
        {

        }

        private static DatabaseContext _db;
        private static object _lockObjesi = new object();
        public static DatabaseContext CreateContext()
        {
            if (_db == null)
            {
                lock (_lockObjesi)  
                {
                    if (_db == null)
                    {
                        _db = new DatabaseContext();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _db;
        }
    }
```

Note Entity:

```
    public class Note : MyEntitesBase
    {       
        public string Tittle { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool IsDraft { get; set; }
        public int LikeCount { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        public virtual EvernoteUser Owner { get; set; } 
        public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; } 
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; } 
        public virtual List<Liked> Likes { get; set; } 

        public Note()
        {
            Comments = new List<Comment>();
            Likes = new List<Liked>();
        }

    }
```

Comment Entity :

```
    public class Comment : MyEntitesBase
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool CommentStatus { get; set; }

        public virtual Note Note { get; set; }
        public virtual EvernoteUser Owner { get; set; } 
    }
```

Comment: try to add  ``Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`` in the constructor ``public DatabaseContext()``

Comment: Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; When I do, I can't take the comments added to the note. The system doesn't work properly.

Comment: can you share ``Comments`` and ``Note`` entities

Comment: I updated the post. I also added "Note and comment" entities

Comment: keep the ``Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`` and when getting ``Notes`` include ``Comments`` like ``db.Notes.Include(p => p.Comments)``

Comment: There is no access to the DAL from the entity layer. How can I do it?

Comment: Create new method in ``Repository<T>`` like : ``public List<T> QueryObjectGraph(string children)
{
    return db.Set<T>().Include(children).ToList();
}`` and call it ``QueryObjectGraph("Comments")``before calling ``db.Notes`` form example